# Use appropriate test to examine convergence of the series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am given the following series, and then I have to test for convergence. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{n-1}{n+1})^{n(n-1)}$. I have tried both ratio and root, and both seems to end up nowhere after lots of computation. Are both bad choices (xor) am I lacking technical skills to do the right manipulation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option I would recommend is to forget for a moment these all-too-famous tests and to try to *think* about the behaviour of the $n$th term of the series at hand when $n$ is large. Does it go to zero? How fast? Like a power of $\frac1n$? Or like a geometric sequence such as $\frac1{2^n}$? And is this enough to deduce the convergence or the divergence of the series?

In the present case, standard inequalities yield the following, which should help you to conclude:
$$\frac{n-1}{n+1}\leqslant1-\frac1n\leqslant\mathrm e^{-1/n}\implies\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)^{n(n-1)}\leqslant\mathrm e^{-(n-1)}$$

Comment: Thank you very much, I need much practice with inequalities, etc, ... I have focused to much on the conceptual rather than the technical.

Answer (score 3):

By the root test

$$\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)^{n(n-1)}}=\left(\frac{n-1}{n+1}\right)^{n-1}=\left(1+\frac{2}{n-1}\right)^{1-n}=\exp\left((1-n)\log\left(1+\frac{2}{n-1}\right)\right)\sim_\infty e^{-2}<1$$
so the series is convergent.

Comment: Thank you Sami! I don't "see" how you got from the second to the third equality but I will find me some paper and try.